# LibGDX create game menu like Flappy Bird?

Tags: user-interface, libgdx, game-engine, 2d-games, flappy-bird-clone

I´m have a question about LibGDX Game Engine.

1. Im always use SpriteBatch to draw on screen, now I will make the same game menu like Flappy Bird. In Flappy Bird the menu comes into the game screen, so flappy bird don´t have more screens, he take it all on the same screen. Can i do this with a stage and scene2D or can i use SpriteBatch for this?
2. On Stage I can use actions to rotate my textures, is that doable with SpriteBatch too?

Hope you can help me, sorry for my bad english :)

Greetings coco07 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For UI with libgdx i would always use `Scene2dUI`. To let you know: `scene2D` uses `SpriteBatch`. A scene2D Stage has its own `Camera` and `SpriteBatch`, you can manipulate. This gives you the possibility to move the `Camera` for this `Stage` arround. You can simply draw your game-stuff and when you need a menu, call the `stage.draw()` in your `render()` method. This calls `draw()` for every `Actor` on this `Stage`. For menus i would suggest to use [TableLayout](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout). One thing to remember: Call `spritebatch.end()` before calling `stage.draw()`.
Also read this: [Scene2D](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d)
Hope it helps.

Comment: I need only 3 buttons in the game menu. I don´t think, that I need a table layout or scene2dUI for this? I had make that today morning, i used 2 Stages for that, the first for the game screen and the second for the menu.

Comment: For the menu i would use scene2dui as it was made for this.

Comment: Just for curiosity: Are you using 2 stages now? So one for menu and one for game?

Comment: Yes, but it don´t works great. I tried to use one SpriteBatch and one Stage separate and it works great!